# Logger for android that vertically aligns log

Tags: java, android, logging

Is there a logger out there that brings the power of the popular loggers like Androlog, SLF4J Android, Log4J - Android but aligns the log in logcat in a vertical manner like this across the whole application:

```
09-01 17:03:08.042 V/App: .backend.RestClient - (RestClient.java:57)                               : serverAddress >> https://host.com/
09-01 17:03:08.052 I/App: .backend.RestClient - (RestClient.java:65)                               : build custom okHttpClient
09-01 17:03:08.132 I/App: .activity.MainActivity - (MainActivity.java:124)                         : MainActivity onPause
09-01 17:03:08.192 D/App: .gcm.RegistrationIntentService - (RegistrationIntentService.java:39)     : GCM Registration Token: AAASDFASDFASDF
09-01 17:03:08.192 I/App: .gcm.PushRegistrar - (PushRegistrar.java:40)                             : setPushToken, request >> PushToken(pushToken=....
09-01 17:03:08.332 I/App: .backend.Request$5 - (Request.java:372)                                  : account/login >> statusCode: 200
09-01 17:03:08.332 D/App: .backend.Request$5 - (Request.java:377)                                  : account/login >> account: BaseResponse(result=OK, code=200)
09-01 17:03:08.332 D/App: .backend.Request$5 - (Request.java:385)                                  : account/login >> sessionId :...
09-01 17:03:08.332 I/App: .backend.Request - (Request.java:220)                                    : fetchAccountInfo >> BaseRequest(accountId=12, ...
09-01 17:03:08.372 D/App: .backend.Request - (Request.java:470)                                    : fetchProjects (featured) >> BaseRequest(accountId=12, ...
09-01 17:03:08.372 D/App: .backend.Request - (Request.java:470)                                    : fetchProjects (own) >> BaseRequest(accountId=12, ...
09-01 17:03:08.372 I/App: .gcm.PushRegistrar$1 - (PushRegistrar.java:48)                           : setPushToken, onResponse
09-01 17:03:08.372 I/App: .gcm.PushRegistrar$1 - (PushRegistrar.java:49)                           : setPushToken, statusCode >> 200
09-01 17:03:08.372 I/App: .gcm.PushRegistrar$1 - (PushRegistrar.java:52)                           : setPushToken, response body
09-01 17:03:08.372 D/App: .gcm.PushRegistrar$1 - (PushRegistrar.java:62)                           : set push token >> 200, body >> BaseResponse(result=OK, code=200, ...
09-01 17:03:08.432 D/App: .backend.Request$2 - (Request.java:233)                                  : account >> 200, body >> BaseResponse(result=OK, code=200, ...
09-01 17:03:08.432 I/App: .backend.Request$3 - (Request.java:287)                                  : fetchMe >> 200
09-01 17:03:08.692 I/App: .backend.Request$4 - (Request.java:332)                                  : downloadProfileImg >> success (https://url)
09-01 17:03:08.712 I/App: .backend.Request$6 - (Request.java:484)                                  : fetchProjects (featured) >> statusCode: 200
09-01 17:03:08.712 I/App: .backend.Request$6 - (Request.java:484)                                  : fetchProjects (own) >> statusCode: 200
```